# "Ref does not have a version" error when trying to install an extension locally using Firebase CLI

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments, firebase-tools, firebase-extensions

I installed `stripe/firestore-stripe-payments` extension using Firebase Console (https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/stripe-firestore-stripe-payments) and it works fine.

However, I wanted to install the extension locally so I can have a full testing environment using Firebase Local Emulator Suite.

The issue is that whenever I try to run `firebase ext:install stripe/firestore-stripe-payments` using both `firebase-tools` `11.8.1` and `11.14.1`, it shows the following error:
[image: terminal showing "Error: Ref does not have a version"]

I tried looking online but it seems that this error is not common.

Here's my `firebase.json`:

```json
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "ignore": [
      "node_modules",
      ".git",
      "firebase-debug.log",
      "firebase-debug.*.log"
    ],
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ],
    "source": "functions"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "auth": {
      "port": 9099
    },
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "database": {
      "port": 9000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "storage": {
      "port": 9199
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "pubsub": {
      "port": 8085
    },
    "eventarc": {
      "port": 9299
    }
  },
  "remoteconfig": {
    "template": "remoteconfig.template.json"
  },
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "./web/build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the error by specifying the exact version, according to [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/issues/394#issuecomment-1154977926).

The latest version can be found as `version` in `extension.yaml` in the official repository, which "source code" link in Firebase's extension page can refer to it, in my case:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/blob/master/firestore-stripe-payments/extension.yaml

So, I used this command and it worked!

`firebase ext:install stripe/firestore-stripe-payments@0.3.1`

It took care of the `firebase.json` and `extensions/firestore-stripe-payments.env` automatically.

If you already installed the extension via console.firebase.google.com, use the following command to import the configuration:
`firebase ext:export --project=XXXX`

Then, override any attribute in `extensions/firestore-stripe-payments.env.local` as @darren-ackers mentioned.

There's a pending PR that covers most of these steps in addition to webhook configuration, here's the relevant file (README):

https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/pull/436/files

Comment: This answer should be on top. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The v11 version of firebase-tools works quite differently to previous major versions.

To run locally, you will need to make a few additions.

1). Add an `extensions` object to your `firebase.json` and  use a relative path to point to the route of the stripe extension (basically where the extension.yaml lives).

```
 "extensions": {
    firestore-stripe-payments: "../path-to-extension-yaml"
 }
```

2). Next you will require a new folder to host your extension configuration.

- Add a new folder called "extensions" in the same directory as your firebase.json.
- Create new files for local config (this must match the extension you are attempting to emulate).

For example:

`firestore-stripe-payments.env.local` for main configuration
`firestore-stripe-payments.secret.local` for secrets

```
LOCATION=us-central-1
PRODUCTS_COLLECTION =products
etc...
```

3). Finally, run `firebase emulators:start -P ${project_id}, it is recommended to use the prefix` demo-`, as in` demo-project` to avoid emulating any production services.

For more guidelines with Stripe, the official repository has an example or extensions tests https://github.com/stripe/stripe-firebase-extensions/tree/next/firestore-stripe-payments/_emulator

Comment: Thank you for such detailed response. Do you know where can I find a sample of the `firestore-stripe-payments.env.local` file, or, ideally, copy it directly from https://console.firebase.google.com/?

Comment: Also, do I have to manually clone the repo to obtain the `extension.yaml`?

Comment: Yes, cloning is the best option as this will also have the associated functions to emulate when starting the emulator.